# Adding a new custom lifestyle to Windsor Container

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

I want to add per session lifestyle for one of my controllers in an ASP.NET MVC app but it currently has no such option. I've searched the stackoverflow and found the next solution

```
    public class PerSessionLifestyleManager : AbstractLifestyleManager
    {
        private readonly string PerSessionObjectID = "PerSessionLifestyleManager_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        public override object Resolve(CreationContext context)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[PerSessionObjectID] == null)
            {
                // Create the actual object
                HttpContext.Current.Session[PerSessionObjectID] = base.Resolve(context);
            }

            return HttpContext.Current.Session[PerSessionObjectID];
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
```

But I want to be able to write somethink like

```
 cr => cr.LifeStyle.PerSession.Named(cr.Implementation.Name)
```

I use Castle Windsor 3.0 and found that LifestyleType enum is contained inside Castle.Core namespace, it is being used by the DefaultKernel. My suggestion is to override the DefaultKernel but I do not really know how to do it bug free and seemlessly as if PerSession lifestyle if shipped with the dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two things that you're asking about.

First is how to implement the lifestyle. Good starting point would be to look at how per-web-request lifestyle is implemented (use Scoped lifestyle with custom scope and scope accessor)

Second, how to surface that in the API. what I recommend is to have an extension method that encapsulates your lower level call to `LifestyleScoped<YourCustomScopeAccessor>()` with `LifestylePerSession()` similar to how WCF Facility [does it](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration/Lifestyles/LifestyleRegistrationExtensions.cs#L36).

Comment: The first seems to be implemented in the class posted in the question. But I am not sure I fully get your second suggestion.

Comment: Oh and the lifestyle implementation that you posted is flawed, primarily because it will never release objects.

Comment: I feel like there is a large enough number of web-pages which have a consequential workflow. And for these pages it would be natural to have the session lifestyle. So my last question is - why has not this been implemented in Castle? Was there a reason of not doint it?

Comment: No one seems to have needed it, or cared enough to implement it. Usually it's better to have a per-web-request components that get their shared state from a persistent store than clutter memory with those often large objects that will occupy it unnecessarily. I consider it a bad practice in general

Comment: Yes, but if the app is Intranet and the session objects are reasonbly small, the persistent storage might be an overkill

Comment: Could be. I said it's IMHO a bad practice _in general_ but there are exception to every rule. If you feel it's the right solution for you, go for it.